# How can I update data in bin file in C language?

Tags: c

I want to update the data in a specific index in the file, but I cannot update it.

I read all the data in the loop with `fread()`.

Then, the code I tried:

```
bookData book;
id = 5;
diff = 10;
cfPtr = fopen("library.bin", "rb+");
book.id = id;
strcpy(book.name, bookTemp[id].name);
strcpy(book.author, bookTemp[id].author);
book.quantity = bookTemp[id].quantity + diff;
book.rackno = bookTemp[id].rackno;
    
fseek(cfPtr, (book.id) * sizeof(bookData),SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&book, sizeof(bookData), 1, cfPtr);
fclose(cfPtr);
```

After doing this i was unable to update the data. Also bookData:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id; // book id
    char name[20]; // book name
    char author[20]; // author of book
    int quantity; // quantity of book
    int rackno; // rack no of the book
} bookData;
```

How can I change the quantity of a book?

Comment: Just as a sanity check, do you have write permissions for the .bin file? Some binaries are restricted to only read/execute.

Comment: You need to check the result of `fopen`.  There's a very good chance, it returned a null pointer.  The most likely error is that `library.bin` is not in the current working directory. Happens a lot when running programs from IDEs.

Comment: We can only guess without a working piece of code that demonstrates the issue.  Could be I/O failure, could be that you had a bad string in `bookTemp` and wiped all of memory, could be a piece of unrelated code that you didn't post.  Hard to say without a working sample.

Comment: Aside.  Although this is not your issue,  you seem to be making a manual copy of `bookData`. You could replace most of your copy struct code to be: `memcpy(&book, &bookTemp[id], sizeof(book))` followed by `book.quantity += diff;`   I'm guessing you are just trying to update the quantity of an existing record.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd recommend using the integrals from `stdint.h`, e. g. `int32_t`, and write or read the members one after another instead of the whole struct at once. This improves portability (different platforms might have differing byte alignment or differing size of `int` – though unlikely in given case). Not covered yet, is differing endianness. For the integers, you could solve by shifting and masking out all but the least significant byte.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and after few tweaks it worked and filled right record in right place.
You can check it.

```
int main()
    {
    fill_lib1("library.bin");
    //
    bookData book;
    int id = 5;
    int diff = 10;
    FILE *cfPtr = fopen("library.bin", "rb+");
    book.id = 5;
    strcpy(book.name, "Paradyzja");
    strcpy(book.author, "Zajdel");
    book.quantity = 7;
    book.rackno = 8;

    fseek(cfPtr, (book.id) * sizeof(book), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&book, sizeof(book), 1, cfPtr);
    fclose(cfPtr);

    return 0;
    }
```